# Export output from invoke command to a csv

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a simple script below to give me the local admin group membership for all my servers which I have in a text file.

I get the desired result with no issues in the console but I am looking for a way to have this exported to a CSV file somehow.

Any ideas?

```
$server = Get-Content 'C:\powershell\Scripts\GetLocalAdmin\APAC+Sri 
Lanka\servers.txt'
foreach($item in $servers){
write-host "`n"
$servername = Write-Host "Checking $($item.toupper())" -ForegroundColor 
Green 
write-host "`n"  
$invoke = invoke-command {net localgroup Administrators} -comp $item 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Export-CSV` cmdlet. Note that you either have to create an array to store every return value from your `Invoke-Command` using `$invokes += ...` or just use this:

```
Get-Content 'C:\powershell\Scripts\GetLocalAdmin\APAC+SriLanka\servers.txt' | 
    ForEach-Object {
        invoke-command {net localgroup Administrators} -comp $_ |
            Export-Csv 'your_csv_path.csv'
    }
```

Comment: Hi Martin, the above technique doesn't work when I use $_, its comes back saying "The argument is null or empty"

Comment: what is the content of C:\powershell\Scripts\GetLocalAdmin\APAC+SriLanka\servers.txt

Comment: It has my server name "SRVFP001"

Comment: You probably messed up the path.

Comment: $servers1 = "server6302"
    foreach($item in $servers1){ 
    write-host "`n" 
    Write-Host "Checking $($item.toupper())" -ForegroundColor Green 
    write-host "`n" 
    invoke-command {net localgroup Administrators} -comp $_
    }

Comment: I had used the code you had given, But  i had gotten not so helpful data so I decided to use your technique with my code.. The result I get while running your code is something like this.


"PSComputerName RunspaceId PSShowComputerName Length
servername 82e5499a-480c-487b-a7ea-803e5c8af353 TRUE 29"

Comment: Change the script block within the `Invoke-Command` to this: `{(net localgroup Administrators).where({$_ -match '-{79}'},'skipuntil') -notmatch '-{79}|The command completed'}`

Comment: I think, I may have to use a different technique to get the local admin info. The way the result is coming out, its just doesn't want to be piped out!